# Importar librerias en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, importación

Buen día, Tengo una pregunta:
Vengo de Python y soy nuevo en JavaScript he visto que en este lenguaje las importaciones de librerias se hacen con una etiqueta script en un html habiendo colocado las mismas en la carpeta del proyecto.
Otra forma es en Node.js con la funcion require.
Quisiera saber si hay una forma similar a como se haría en Python:

```
from 'libreria' import 'funcion'
```

De esta forma no es necesario tener la libreria en la carpeta del proyecto, como en el caso de la etiqueta script. Ni tener instalado Node.js. Cual seria la forma para importarla solo teniendola instalada como en el caso de Python.

Comment: Creo que estás buscando esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, en javascript no se instalan las librerías. Si lo que quieres es no tenerla en tu carpeta de proyecto, siempre puedes hacer <script scr="https://"> y obtenerla de la web. ¿Si no quieres la librería en la carpeta del proyecto en donde la quieres tener? Se que no puedes responderme en los comentarios, quizás puedas editar tu pregunta para aclarar un poco mis dudas.

Comment: @ArielMontes en JavaScript directamente no, pero en NodeJS y en el navegador tambien asi que, no seamos tan complejas con los comentarios a los usuarios que estan aprendiendo

Comment: Si pedí más información es porque hubo algo que no entendí, no porque la pregunta de un desconocido me haya "acomplejado" como dices.

Answer (score 0):

En Python las librerías se instalan dentro del propio lenguaje, por lo que al importarlas no es necesario acceder a su ruta, lo que significa que no hace falta colocar la librería junto al proyecto.